# how to traverse array of array(inner array) through for each

Tags: php, mysql

i have the following array

```
$competency = array(
    array(
        "assessment_id" => 2,
        "activity_id" => 1,
        "grade" => 10,
        "competency_grade" => array(
            array(
                "competency_id" => 1,
                "grade" => 10
            ) ,
            array(
                "competency_id" => 1,
                "grade" => 10
            )
        )
    ) ,
    array(
        "assessment_id" => 2,
        "activity_id" => 1,
        "grade" => 10,
        "competency_grade" => array(
            array(
                "competency_id" => 1,
                "grade" => 10
            ) ,
            array(
                "competency_id" => 1,
                "grade" => 10
            )
        )
    )
);
```

i print this as

```
 echo "<pre>";
 print_r($competency);
```

this line give result as

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [assessment_id] => 2
            [activity_id] => 1
            [grade] => 10
            [competency_grade] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [competency_id] => 1
                            [grade] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [competency_id] => 1
                            [grade] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [assessment_id] => 2
            [activity_id] => 1
            [grade] => 10
            [competency_grade] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [competency_id] => 1
                            [grade] => 10
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [competency_id] => 1
                            [grade] => 10
                        )

                )

        )

   )
```

Now i try to insert data in two table in first table i use the key assessment_id,activity_id,grade based on that it return inserted id,and use this inserted id in second table as the below code here

```
foreach ($competency as $key => $value) {
    foreach ($value as $innerkey=>$innervalue)
    {
       //echo "<pre>"; print_r($innerkey[0]);
         $query = "insert into grading set user_id = '".$user_id."',
                     assessment_id = '".$innervalue['assessment_id']."',
                     activity_id = '".$innervalue['activity_id']."',
                     date = now(),
                     grade = '".$innervalue['grade']."'";

       $result = mysql_query($query);
       $grading_id=  mysql_insert_id();
          if($innerkey=="competency_grade"){
            //foreach ($innervalue as )
            foreach ($innervalue as $mostinnerkey =>$mostinnervalue)
            {
               $query1 = "insert into competency_grade set 
                competency_id = '".$mostinnervalue['competency_id']."',
                grade = '".$mostinnervalue['grade']."' ,
                grading_id = $grading_id  ";
                $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
                echo mysql_error();
              //print_r($mostinnervalue['competency_id']); echo "<br>";
              //print_r($mostinnervalue['grade']);echo "<br>";
          }
      }
    }
}
```

but i am unable to find the solution plz help me

Regards

Comment: and what is the error/problem/warning/question?

Comment: undefined assessment_id, activity_id,grade

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
****your error might fixed use following script****     

foreach ($competency as $key => $value) {
         $query = "insert into grading set user_id = '".$user_id."',
                     assessment_id = '".$value['assessment_id']."',
                     activity_id = '".$value['activity_id']."',
                     date = now(),
                     grade = '".$value['grade']."'";

       $result = mysql_query($query);
       $grading_id=  mysql_insert_id();
       foreach ($value as $innerkey => $innervalue)
       {
            if($innerkey=="competency_grade"){
         foreach ($innervalue as $mostinnerkey =>$mostinnervalue)
              {
                   $query1 = "insert into competency_grade set competency_id = '".$mostinnervalue['competency_id']."',
                                                                grade = '".$mostinnervalue['grade']."' ,   
                                                                grading_id = $grading_id  ";
                    $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
                    echo mysql_error();

              }
            }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need second loop remove it and replace

```
$innervalue['assessment_id']
```

with:

```
$value['assessment_id']
```

Your complete code may look like:

```
foreach ($competency as $key => $value) {
     $query = "insert into grading set user_id = '".$user_id."',
                 assessment_id = '".$value['assessment_id']."',
                 activity_id = '".$value['activity_id']."',
                 date = now(),
                 grade = '".$value['grade']."'";

   $result = mysql_query($query);
   $grading_id=  mysql_insert_id();
   $query1 = "insert into competency_grade set 
         competency_id = '".$value['competency_grade']['competency_id']."',
         grade = '".$value['competency_grade']['grade']."' ,
         grading_id = $grading_id  ";
         $result1 = mysql_query($query1);
            echo mysql_error();
}
```

Comment: i got error like this  Notice: Undefined index: competency_id in /opt/lampp/htdocs/toolkit/array.php on line 74

Notice: Undefined index: grade in /opt/lampp/htdocs/toolkit/array.php on line 75

Notice: Undefined index: competency_id in /opt/lampp/htdocs/toolkit/array.php on line 74

Notice: Undefined index: grade in /opt/lampp/htdocs/toolkit/array.php on line 75

Comment: Did u try my code? I changed the second loop and variables as well

Answer (score 0):

You can do like

```
 function traversearray($array)
{
    foreach($array as $key=>$value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            traversearray($value);
        }
        else
        {
            echo "key = $key value = $value<br/>";
       }
    }
}
traversearray($competency);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursive function or array_walk_recursive or iterators 
Try below code for manual traverse

```
<?php
function array_traverse($competency){
    foreach($competency as $key => $val){
        if(is_array($val)){
            array_traverse($val);
        } else{
            echo $val;
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
fun($competency);

function fun($value)
{
  foreach ($value as $val)
  {
     if( is_array($val))
       fun($val);
     echo $val;
  }
}
```

Try this.....!